# Getting precise mouse movement deltas while application is not in foreground

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, input, mouse

I am trying to figure out how to get precise mouse movement information from the Win32 API in a way that still works when my application is not focused. So far, I have tried three different approaches:

1. Registering for `WM_MOUSEMOVE` events through `SetWindowsHookEx` with `WH_MOUSE_LL`. This works while the application is in the background, but returns screen coordinates which are relatively low-precision. Also, pointer ballistics are applied to these values, making them less than ideal for my purposes.
2. Calling `GetCursorPos` in a loop. This also works in the background, but again, it returns low-resolution screen coordinates and pointer acceleration is applied.
3. Registering for raw input via `RegisterRawInputDevices` and then watching for `WM_INPUT` events (with calls to `GetRawInputData` to actually access the data). This one -- at least, according to the docs -- returns coordinates in native mouse units, so it is as precise as possible. Unfortunately, this only works when the application is focused. [The docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645543(v=vs.85).aspx) say:

   > An application can receive data when it is in the foreground and when it is in the background.

   But I have not seen any behavior that corroborates these claims.

Since my main question is regarding the third option, I have included my code for that one below.

So, how can I access the native mouse values in a way that works even when the application doesn't have focus? Is there extra configuration needed to make #3 work, or are there other options?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
// ...

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

HWND mainWindow;

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_MOUSETEST, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_MOUSETEST));

    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MOUSETEST));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_MOUSETEST);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   mainWindow = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | RIDEV_INPUTSINK,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!mainWindow)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(mainWindow, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(mainWindow);

   // Register for raw input events

   RAWINPUTDEVICE targetDevice = { 0x01, 0x02, 0, mainWindow };
   BOOL registerRawSuccess = RegisterRawInputDevices(&targetDevice, 1, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICE));

   if (!registerRawSuccess)
       return FALSE;

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    // ...
    case WM_INPUT :
        {
            UINT dwSize = 40;
            static BYTE lpb[40];

            if (GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT,
                NULL, &dwSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)) == -1)
            {
                // TODO: Handle this... something broke
            }

            UINT result = GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT,
                lpb, &dwSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));

            RAWINPUT* raw = (RAWINPUT*)lpb;

            if (raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE)
            {
                // Use raw->data.mouse.lLastX and raw->data.mouse.lLastY
            }
            break;
        }
    // ...
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you setting the `RIDEV_INPUTSINK` flag when you register for raw input?

Comment: `WM_INPUT` is issued directly by the input device at a lower level where input focus does not apply. Background processes receive `WM_INPUT` just fine. If you are not receiving it, you are doing something wrong. But you did not show your code.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Yes, I believe I am. See the code I added in the question; I could easily have done something wrong.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry, my code was pretty long and I didn't want to pollute the post if it wasn't wanted. I have edited to include my test code for the `WM_INPUT` events.

Comment: @WasabiFan no, actually you are *not* using `RIDEV_INPUTSINK`. You are setting the `RAWINPUTDEVICE::dwFlags` field to 0. `RIDEV_INPUTSINK` is 0x00000100.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ahhhh, that works. I was using it wrong. Would you mind writing up an answer with that suggestion so I can mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the Raw Input API, specify the `RIDEV_INPUTSINK` flag if you want to receive `WM_INPUT` messages while your app is running in the background:

> If set, this enables the caller to receive the input **even when the caller is not in the foreground**. Note that `hwndTarget` must be specified.

Change this line:

```
RAWINPUTDEVICE targetDevice = { 0x01, 0x02, 0, mainWindow };
```

To this:

```
RAWINPUTDEVICE targetDevice = { 0x01, 0x02, RIDEV_INPUTSINK, mainWindow };
```